# C++ Socket recv() always returns 0

Tags: sockets, c++11, pointers, recv, pointer-conversion

This does work:

```
char blockSize[4];
int r = recv(socket, blockSize, 4, 0);
```

This does not work. It always returns zero, why?

```
size_t blockSize = 0;
int r = recv(socket, (char*)blockSize, 4, 0);
```

It's not a major problem, I know how to convert the char array back to a size_t. But I just want to know why it's not working.

Comment: Did you mean to write `(char *) &blockSize`? Otherwise you're just passing the pointer 0.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Oh yes of course -.- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 1st example, you are passing the *address* of `blockSize` (via array decay) to `recv()`.

In the 2nd example, you are passing the *value* of `blockSize` to `recv()`, type-casted as a pointer. Since `blockSize` is 0, the pointer is effectively `nullptr`.  You need to pass the *address* of `blockSize` instead. Also, `size_t` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes, so use `(u)int32_t` instead, eg:

```
uint32_t blockSize = 0;
int r = recv(socket, (char*)&blockSize, 4, 0);
```